# Как определить id пользователя по фотографии?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Есть, допустим, вывод всех пользователей (в виде фотографий) из таблицы:

```
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $userfoto = $row['img'];
    echo '<img src="'.$userfoto.'">';
```

Как определить id пользователя по фото? Чтобы например писать в личку или узнать личную информацию пользователя.

Comment: А назвзние очень интригующее... Хотел увидеть ответ про OpenCV, распознаие картинок и  ... Эх...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

использовать поле с автоинкриментом(обычно это id) так

```
$userid = $row['id'];
```

ну или какие поле отвечает за автоинкримент.

Comment: Я наверно поскупился в вопросе) Id то в таблице стоит с автоинкриментом, Меня интересует сам код ajax, Чтобы при клике на фотку, я получал данные с базы, конкретного пользователя. Типо что то $(this).data('userid')

Comment: ну так добавте таким образом  echo '<img src="'.$userfoto.' data-id="'$row['id']'" ">';   ну и потом в js $('img').click(function(){
var id =$(this).data('id');
}) ну и дальше ajaxом передать

Comment: спасибо! ) помогли!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста